# Embed Excel logic in .NET code for complex formulas

Tags: .net, excel

We have a situation where Excel works extraordinarily well for some formulas that we're using. We're in the process of converting those formulas to .NET code with unit tests, but the Excel spreadsheet does a much better job of structuring the logic.

Ideally, we would take our input values from .NET and send them over to the Excel engine, and read out the results.

Using Excel automation seems like overkill in complexity. Is there an efficient library that would let me read in the excel file, set some cells, and read out the results?

Answer (score 0):

Try [NPOI](http://npoi.codeplex.com/), I have used that successfully in the past. It will allow you to do exactly what you require.

Comment: Will it fun the formulas as well?

Comment: Yes it will. You'll be able to read any cell in the spreadsheet.

Comment: This library looks like it will read and write Excel files, but I'll still have to fire up Excel to get it to recalculate the formulas.